# symfony form embeding other forms, how to reach form_errors/validation.message

Tags: forms, validation, symfony-forms, symfony

I am having trouble on Symfony3 to display {{ form_errors([formname.field]) }} messages with a form embedding other forms.

I've dropped a symfony project on GitHub to explain my issue:
https://github.com/nyluje/symfony_test_form_embedded

You'll find in it:

- \src\AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php modified to display
  the test.
- Under \src\AppBundle\Entity\ two entities: EntityForFormA and
  EntityForFromB created with a "field1" being of EmailType.
- Under \src\AppBundle\Form: 3 forms files; 2 Are directly related to
  the EntityForFormA and EntityForFormB: FormAType and FormBType, and
  the last one FormCType is there to embed both into one form.

At the top of the file \app\Resources\default\index.hmtl.twig:

```
{{ form_start(form_a) }}
    {{ form_label(form_a.field1) }}
    {{ form_widget(form_a.field1) }}
    {{ form_errors(form_a.field1) }}
{{ form_end(form_a) }}

{{ form_start(form_c) }}
    {{ form_label(form_c.FormA.field1) }}
    {{ form_widget(form_c.FormA.field1) }}
    {{ form_errors(form_c.FormA.field1) }}

    {{ form_label(form_c.FormB.field1) }}
    {{ form_widget(form_c.FormB.field1) }}
    {{ form_errors(form_c.FormB.field1) }}
{{ form_end(form_c) }}
```

If you do a form A submit with value "j@j" you get:
[image]
The error message "This value is not a valid email address" is clearly displayed.

Now if you submit form C with value "j@j" in both fields: 
[image]

**The error message "This value is not a valid email address" is not displayed.**

Does anyone know why the error messages don't display in case of FormC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default validation won't traverse to properties that are objects or collections. Use the [valid constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html):

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html

You cans set the traverse option for collections as well.

Comment: Thanks @Richard! Following your hint lead me to a solution, also I don't find it intuitive at all (had to create an extra EntityForFormC with attributes entityForFormA and entityForFormB in it, and setEntityForFormA-B on it inside the controller). I fell that It would have been more consistant to have  {{ form_errors([parentForm].[embeddeForm].[fieldOfEmbeddedFrom]) }} to work when you have   {{ form_label([parentForm].[embeddeForm].[fieldOfEmbeddedFrom]) }} and  {{ form_widget([parentForm].[embeddeForm].[fieldOfEmbeddedFrom]) }} which do the job that way.